# Parsley.remote.js throws an error - $.emit is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, parsley.js

For reason unknown, when validating form element with ajax, I get this error:

> TypeError: $.emit is not a function
>
> ...){var b=this,c=[];this._refreshFields(),$.emit("parsley:form:validate",this);for...

in `parsley.remote.min.js`. Anyone know why? I load scripts in this order (in the `<head>`)

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.remote.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pl.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

`$.emit` is not a jQuery function but is provided by Parsley. So you must include Parsley before Parsley.remote:

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.0.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/parsley.remote.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pl.js"></script>
```

Comment: It should be noted... you no longer need to include both Parsley and Parsley.remote -- one or the other.  See the doc here: http://parsleyjs.org/doc/#remote